# Multiple Python scripts running concurrently with different inputs

Tags: python, selenium

So I have this python script that scrapes listing off of a specific craigslist URL the user constructs (location, max price, type of item, etc.). It then goes to the URL, scrapes the listings info (price, date posted, etc) and returns three outputs. One is 'x' number of items around the average price (the user determines the number of items and the range of prices such as $100 off the average price). Next, are 'x' closets listings based of the zip code the user provided in the begging (user also determine the # of items displayed based on proximity to zip code). Lastly the craigslist url link is outputted to the user so they can visit the page and look at the items displayed to them earlier. The data of the scrape is stored in a data.json file and a data.csv file .Content is the same just different formats, I would like to offload this data to a Database everytime a scrape is done. Either Cloud Firestore or AWS DynamoDB since I want to host this a web app in the future

What I want to do is allow the user to have multiple instances of the same scripts all with unique craigslist urls running at the same time. All of the code is the same, the only difference are the craigslist urls that the script scrapes.

I made a method that iterated through the creation of the attributes(location, max price, etc) and returns a lost of the urls, but in my main I call the contructor and it needs all of those attributes so I have to fish it from the urls and that seemed over the top.

I then tried to have the loop in my main. the user determine how many url links they want to make and append the completed links to a list. Again ran into the same problem.

```
class CraigslistScraper(object):

# Contructor of the URL that is being scraped
def __init__(self, location, postal_code, max_price, query, radius):
    self.location = location  # Location(i.e. City) being searched
    self.postal_code = postal_code  # Postal code of location being searched
    self.max_price = max_price  # Max price of the items that will be searched
    self.query = query  # Search for the type of items that will be searched
    self.radius = radius  # Radius of the area searched derived from the postal code given previously

    self.url = f"https://{location}.craigslist.org/search/sss?&max_price={max_price}&postal={postal_code}&query={query}&20card&search_distance={radius}"
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver")  # Path of Firefox web driver
    self.delay = 7  # The delay the driver gives when loading the web page

# Load up the web page
# Gets all relevant data on the page
# Goes to next page until we are at the last page
def load_craigslist_url(self):

    data = []
    # url_list = []
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    while True:
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay)
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchform")))
            data.append(self.extract_post_titles())
            # url_list.append(self.extract_post_urls())
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchform"]/div[3]/div[3]/span[2]/a[3]'))).click()
        except:
            break
    return data

# Extracts all relevant information from the web-page and returns them as individual lists
def extract_post_titles(self):

    all_posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-row")

    dates_list = []
    titles_list = []
    prices_list = []
    distance_list = []

    for post in all_posts:

        title = post.text.split("$")

        if title[0] == '':
            title = title[1]
        else:
            title = title[0]

        title = title.split("\n")
        price = title[0]
        title = title[-1]
        title = title.split(" ")
        month = title[0]
        day = title[1]
        title = ' '.join(title[2:])
        date = month + " " + day

        if not price[:1].isdigit():
            price = "0"
        int(price)

        raw_distance = post.find_element_by_class_name(
            'maptag').text
        distance = raw_distance[:-2]

        titles_list.append(title)
        prices_list.append(price)
        dates_list.append(date)
        distance_list.append(distance)

    return titles_list, prices_list, dates_list, distance_list

# Gets all of the url links of each listing on the page
# def extract_post_urls(self):
#     soup_list = []
#     html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.driver.current_url)
#     soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
#     for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "result-title hdrlnk"}):
#         soup_list.append(link["href"])
#
#     return soup_list

# Kills browser
def kill(self):
    self.driver.close()

# Gets price value from dictionary and computes average
@staticmethod
def get_average(sample_dict):

    price = list(map(lambda x: x['Price'], sample_dict))
    sum_of_prices = sum(price)
    length_of_list = len(price)
    average = round(sum_of_prices / length_of_list)

    return average

# Displays items around the average price of all the items in prices_list
@staticmethod
def get_items_around_average(avg, sample_dict, counter, give):
    print("Items around average price: ")
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    raw_list = []
    for z in range(len(sample_dict)):
        current_price = sample_dict[z].get('Price')
        if abs(current_price - avg) <= give:
            raw_list.append(sample_dict[z])
    final_list = raw_list[:counter]
    for index in range(len(final_list)):
        print('\n')
        for key in final_list[index]:
            print(key, ':', final_list[index][key])

# Displays nearest items to the zip provided
@staticmethod
def get_items_around_zip(sample_dict, counter):
    final_list = []
    print('\n')
    print("Closest listings: ")
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    x = 0
    while x < counter:
        final_list.append(sample_dict[x])
        x += 1
    for index in range(len(final_list)):
        print('\n')
        for key in final_list[index]:
            print(key, ':', final_list[index][key])

# Converts all_of_the_data list of dictionaries to json file
@staticmethod
def convert_to_json(sample_list):
    with open(r"C:\Users\diego\development\WebScraper\data.json", 'w') as file_out:
        file_out.write(json.dumps(sample_list, indent=4))

@staticmethod
def convert_to_csv(sample_list):
    df = pd.DataFrame(sample_list)
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, header=True)


# Main where the big list data is broken down to its individual parts to be converted to a .csv file
```

## also the parameters of the website are set

if **name** == "**main**":

```
location = input("Enter the location you would like to search: ")  # Location Craigslist searches
zip_code = input(
    "Enter the zip code you would like to base radius off of: ")  # Postal code Craigslist uses as a base for 'MILES FROM ZIP'
type_of_item = input(
    "Enter the item you would like to search (ex. furniture, bicycles, cars, etc.): ")  # Type of item you are looking for
max_price = input(
    "Enter the max price you would like the search to use: ")  # Max price Craigslist limits the items too
radius = input(
    "Enter the radius you would like the search to use (based off of zip code provided earlier): ")  # Radius from postal code Craigslist limits the search to

scraper = CraigslistScraper(location, zip_code, max_price, type_of_item,
                            radius)  # Constructs the URL with the given parameters

results = scraper.load_craigslist_url()  # Inserts the result of the scrapping into a large multidimensional list

titles_list = results[0][0]
prices_list = list(map(int, results[0][1]))
dates_list = results[0][2]
distance_list = list(map(float, results[0][3]))

scraper.kill()

# Merge all of the lists into a dictionary
# Dictionary is then sorted by distance from smallest -> largest
list_of_attributes = []

for i in range(len(titles_list)):
    content = {'Listing': titles_list[i], 'Price': prices_list[i], 'Date posted': dates_list[i],
               'Distance from zip': distance_list[i]}
    list_of_attributes.append(content)

list_of_attributes.sort(key=lambda x: x['Distance from zip'])

scraper.convert_to_json(list_of_attributes)
scraper.convert_to_csv(list_of_attributes)
# scraper.export_to_mongodb()

# Below function calls:
# Get average price and prints it
# Gets/prints listings around said average price
# Gets/prints nearest listings

average = scraper.get_average(list_of_attributes)
print(f'Average price of items searched: ${average}')
num_items_around_average = int(input("How many listings around the average price would you like to see?: "))
avg_range = int(input("Range of listings around the average price: "))
scraper.get_items_around_average(average, list_of_attributes, num_items_around_average, avg_range)
print("\n")
num_items = int(input("How many items would you like to display based off of proximity to zip code?: "))
print(f"Items around you: ")
scraper.get_items_around_zip(list_of_attributes, num_items)
print("\n")
print(f"Link of listings : {scraper.url}")
```

What i want is the program to get the number of URLs the user wants to scrape. That input will determine the number of instances of this script that needs to be running.

Then the user will run through the prompt of every scraper such as making the url ("what location would you like to search?: "). After they are done creating the urls, each scraper will run with their specific url and display back the three output described above specific to the url the scraper was assigned.

In the future I would like to add a time function and the user determines how often they want the script to run (every hour, every day, every other day, etc). Connect to a database and instead just query from the database the the 'x' # of listings around the average price range and the 'x' closest listings based off of proximity based of the specific url's results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want several instances of your scraper in parallel while your main is running in loop, you need to use subprocceses.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html